# Windows 7 IIS 7.5 ASPX Pages Hang IIS in Application migrated from IIS6

Tags: iis, iis-6, asp.net, iis-7.5

I am migrating a web application from IIS6 to IIS7.5 and I'm having a few strange issues with this.

My web application will serve up .html or .asp pages, but when I try to request a .aspx page it locks up IIS for about a minute or so, and I can't even view the asp page that I was able to view before IIS was locked up.

I've been trying to fix this for about a month and have tried many things but I really can't figure it out.

Things I've tried already:

- Switching the application pool to the Classic .NET AppPool
- enabled port 80 and 443 on windows firewall
- Running aspnet_regiis -i
- Enabled 32 bit web applications
- Set Load User Profile = False on my application pool
- icacls %WINDIR%\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\temp
  /grant IUSR:(CI)(RX,WD,AD)
- icacls %WINDIR%\serviceprofiles\networkservice\AppData\Local\Temp
  /grant "CREATOR
  OWNER":(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)

Other notes of interest: When I try edit the markup of an ASPX page in visual studio 2008 in this web application, it hangs visual studio and I have to force end the visual studio process. So I can't edit any aspx pages with the visual studio 2008 editor in the same application. However if I start a new ASP.NET website I don't have any problems editing the ASPX pages. Also, it was originally compiled on Server 2003 32 bit, and I had to enable 32 bit applications in my application pool, otherwise I would get a "not a valid 64 bit application error"

Edit: Also when I request an ASPX page from my broken application, it totally hangs IIS and it won't even serve .asp or .html pages until it either recycles itself or I manually recycle the application pool

Running Software:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- IIS 7.5

I am really stuck here, any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out. There was a 3rd party DLL in the project called `safileup.dll` that was being used to upload files on the application. Removing that file from the bin directory fixed my hanging issues.

The dll in question was `softartisans fileup`. We will be discontinuing use of this add on.

Comment: Moral of the story: Make sure 3rd party add ons are compatible in your new environment first!

Comment: I had exactly same issue and it was the safileup.dll :)